# confusion regarding matrix derivative question

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

This is the question from the book Mathematics for machine learning  [image]

how to get to this step[image]

because using the identities from this book[image]

the derivative of $g(y)$ w.r.t. $y$ should be $(y^T(S^{-1} + (S^T)^{-1})$ .
which is not same as the answer so in the given identities what are the conditions on $X$ matrix

Comment: What is the $S$ matrix? It would be correct if $S^\top = S$. Since this book is on machine learning I'll guess that $S$ is the covariance matrix and thus symmetric.

Comment: Yeah, it probably was overlooked in the solution since the exercise itself has no mention about the context of the problem. I'd say just assume that $S^{-1}$ is symmetric, or do your own computation with the identity you posted and compare the results.